# I am not able to bind the datepicker value with my calling function in angular2.

Tags: html, angular, css, datepicker

I have used a JQuery date-picker. The error coming while i am selecting date is: 
"(MySelectedDate) does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd""

Comment: May you post some code ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow community.
Read it for posting good questions :)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which module you are using for acheive it